# Is there a way to identify change in one variable after certain event

Tags: sql

My Table looks like this...Any way to identify when loanamt changed after disb date?

[image: table]

Comment: Neither loanamt nor disb_date are in your sample data.  But you could use a trigger for this purpose.

Comment: what DBMS do you use?

Comment: RDMS i believe is the answer to what you are asking..I was trying to see if there is a way to write a statement to identify this instance...not a store proc or trigger...I cant do those...I'm just an analyst sitting outside of IT looking at read only table in a db and querying it with SSMS

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
select
    x.*,
    y.key is not null as changed_after_disb_date
from
    <table_name> as x
    left join ( select
                    key,
                    date(outval) as disb_date
                from
                    <table_name>
                where
                    varname = 'DISB_DATE') as y on  x.key = y.key
                                                    and x.servertimestamp > y.disb_date
```