# Are there any way to identify whether any column value changed during a certain time period base on a "change history" table which related with an ID?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two dataset examples below with the first table containing all the data related to work orders, and the second table containing the changes history on each work order.

History Table

```
+---------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| WORK_ID |  TIME  |  FIELD  | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
+---------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| A2      | 09.02  | SALES   | 150       | 250       |
| A1      | 09.00  | STATUS  | CLOSED    | OPEN      |
| A1      | 08.55  | OWNER   | LISA      | DEBBY     |
| A2      | 08.54  | STATUS  | CLOSED    | OPEN      |
| A2      | 08.50  | STATUS  | OPEN      | CLOSED    |
| A1      | 08.45  | SALES   | 300       | 500       |
| A1      | 08.45  | STATUS  | OPEN      | CLOSED    |
| A2      | 08.40  | OWNER   | ROB       | ANDY      |
+---------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Work Order Table

```
+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| WORK_ID |  STATUS | OWNER  | SALES | 
+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| A1      | OPEN    | DEBBY  | 500   |
| A2      | OPEN    | ANDY   | 250   |
+---------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Both of the tables are related to each other with the WORK_ID column. My goal is to identify whether any field was changed after a work order status is changed to CLOSED and before it is changed to OPEN.

I have tried using CASE and WHEN and also solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311196/is-there-a-way-to-identify-change-in-one-variable-after-certain-event), but I am still unable to isolate only the changes between when the status was changed to CLOSED (field STATUS new value is CLOSED) to the status was changed to OPEN (field STATUS new value is OPEN).

I am expecting an output table looked like this,

```
+---------+---------+--------+-------+-------------------+
| WORK_ID |  STATUS | OWNER  | SALES | CHANGED_ON_CLOSED |
+---------+---------+--------+-------+-------------------+
| A1      | OPEN    | DEBBY  | 500   | TRUE              |
| A2      | OPEN    | ANDY   | 250   | FALSE             |
+---------+---------+--------+-------+-------------------+
```

Would anybody be willing to help to show me an SQL query that would do this?

Comment: Hi @rahmadidr, Did the answer below help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

To combine these tables, please pivot the first table.

If you only need to see whats happend during closing statements:

```sql
With tbl as (
Select"A2" WORK_ID,"9,02" TIME,"SALES" FIELD,"150" OLD_VALUE,"250"NEW_VALUE
Union all Select"A1","9","STATUS","CLOSED","OPEN",
Union all Select"A1","8,55","OWNER","LISA","DEBBY",
Union all Select"A2","8,54","STATUS","CLOSED","OPEN",
Union all Select"A2","8,5","STATUS","OPEN","CLOSED",
Union all Select"A1","8,45","SALES","300","500",
Union all Select"A1","8,45","STATUS","OPEN","CLOSED",
Union all Select"A2","8,4","OWNER","ROB","ANDY",
)

SELECT
*,
last_value(if(Field="STATUS",new_value,null) ignore nulls) over win as status,
sum(if(Field="STATUS",1,0)) over win as status_cycle,

from tbl
qualify status="CLOSED" and Field!="STATUS"
window win as  (partition by WORK_ID order by time rows between unbounded preceding and current row)

order by 1,2
```

But I guess you need to use pivot on the first table to join it with the 2nd.

```sql
With tbl as (
Select"A2" WORK_ID,"9,02" TIME,"SALES" FIELD,"150" OLD_VALUE,"250"NEW_VALUE
Union all Select"A1","9","STATUS","CLOSED","OPEN",
Union all Select"A1","8,55","OWNER","LISA","DEBBY",
Union all Select"A2","8,54","STATUS","CLOSED","OPEN",
Union all Select"A2","8,5","STATUS","OPEN","CLOSED",
Union all Select"A1","8,45","SALES","300","500",
Union all Select"A1","8,45","STATUS","OPEN","CLOSED",
Union all Select"A2","8,4","OWNER","ROB","ANDY",
),
helper as (
Select Time,WORK_ID,Owner,Status,Sales from tbl
pivot (any_value (new_value) for field in ("OWNER","STATUS","SALES") )
),

list as (
SELECT WORK_ID,time,
any_value(Owner) Owner,
any_value(Status) Status,
any_value(Sales) Sales,

from helper
group by 1,2)

Select 
WORK_ID,time,
last_value(Owner ignore nulls) over win as owner,
last_value(Status ignore nulls) over win as Status,
last_value(Sales ignore nulls) over win as Sales,
 from list
window win as  (partition by WORK_ID order by time rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
order by 2
```